# Git clone issue, clone fails with "Corrupted MAC on input"

Tags: git, unfuddle

I am trying to set up a new dev machine and I am not able to clone any repos.

```
remote: Counting objects: 99504, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (22812/22812), done.
Corrupted MAC on input. (93674/99504), 169.15 MiB | 3.06 MiB/s   
Disconnecting: Packet corrupt
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: Yeah, trying to figure out what it means.

Answer (score 2):

The server is probably straining under too much load. See this post (similar problem but with rsync in stead of git):

> [The problem was that the origin server had some big load on it, the server was running out of memory and it was swaping a lot (extracted from the top command)](http://blog.e-shell.org/270)

Comment: Thanks, this might have been the issue. Still looking into it though.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be due to a hardware issue. Try troubleshooting your hardware by bypassing any intermediary interfaces (switches, routers, etc) or trying a different NIC.

If it is a hardware issue you may also see problems when accessing large files via other protocols.

Answer (score 0):

A git-daemon restart should give a possible solution (it did to me).