# "Corrupted MAC on input." when git clone over SSH on VPN from VirtualBox/Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

Here is the error after I do a git clone in my Virtualbox which is using Ubuntu 16.04.

Corrupted MAC on input. (33872/116798), 2.67 MiB | 5.30 MiB/s
 
ssh_dispatch_run_fatal: Connection to 10.x.x.x port 2xxxx: message authentication code incorrect
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOFs:  30% (35040/116798), 2.67 MiB | 5.30 MiB/s
fatal: index-pack failed

Couple of things to note:

1. Running through VPN (Company use)
2. Virtualbox Network settings:(Allows me to get to any company sites but cannot connect to google)

   - First Adapter: NAT
   - Second Adapter: Host-Only-Adapter 3) Already installed openssh-client -> version 7.2 4)
3. Generated a rsa key and added it to teamforge account settings

Sorry new to virtualbox but could this be a network issue? Could this be a SSH issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, looks like an SSH issue. Without details, hard to say what.

For leads checkout:

- [Corrupted MAC on input" when SSH connecting - The Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2283665)
- [sshd: Corrupted MAC on input.](http://blog.e-shell.org/270)
- [1230992 – ssh "Corrupted MAC on input." from using wrong MAC method](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1230992)
- [sftp problem: corrupted mac on input](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/sftp-problem-corrupted-mac-on-input-88555/)
- [Git clone issue, clone fails with "Corrupted MAC on input" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366907/git-clone-issue-clone-fails-with-corrupted-mac-on-input)
- [ssh on windows - Corrupted MAC on input - Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/994646/ssh-on-windows-corrupted-mac-on-input)

You'll find plenty more if you search on the error message.